# Cordova CLI - passing args when called from node app

Tags: node.js, cordova

I am trying to use the cordova CLI in a larger Node.js application and running into trouble when trying to figure out how to pass the required arguments to some of the functions.

Specifically, I need to pass the "release" flag to the build function.  I've tried a lot of different combinations, but I've yet to get success

```
using cordova = require('cordova');
```

I've tried:

```
cordova.build('blackberry10', '--release', function(){ //callback code });
```

and I've tried

```
cordova.build('blackberry10 --release', function(){//callback code});
```

and every other combination I can think of.  In the first example, the blackberry10 argument get's processed and the call back does, but the release argument does not.

Any help or thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here, the right answer was to pass the arguments as an object.

```
cordova.build({platforms: ['blackberry10'], options: ['--release', '--keystorepass',    'mysecret']}, function(){
        //callback code
});
```